# Clip/extract the specific cells in a raster that are intersected by a line feature

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, intersect

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.

I have some trail data (line) and some slope data (raster). What I want is a raster layer that is only the cells of the slope layer that are intersected by the line feature. I want to do this without losing the cell values of the slope layer.

I have toyed with the idea of using Polyline to Raster and then trying to do some sort of Overlay like Intersect or something. The problem is apparently you cannot use two rasters for Intersect. I have also seen suggestions for using Raster Multiplication, creating a new raster as the product of the two originals, but this would lose the cell values.

Any ideas?

Comment: Buffer the line feature by some multiple of pixel size, then mask the raster by the buffer.

Comment: You can use two rasters in Con https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/con-.htm this will create a new raster leaving your slope raster pristine.